# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline with Mandatory stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build a Jenkins Declarative pipeline with a Jenkinsfile. The Jenkinsfile would be present on the repo of the project.

The Jenkinsfile would be something like the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    } }
```

However, I would like to enforce some stages in Jenkins regardless of the file. So as an example the pipeline would run Build -> Test -> Deploy stages from the file and an additional stage predefined on Jenkins like if it was a scripted pipeline.

Do you know if this is possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at [Global Post Script plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-post-script/). I don't know if it works with pipeline though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) to reuse code. It won't be as smooth as you probably liked, but you might use [global variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables) and/or [custom steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) to encapsulate common functionality.

This would require some glue code (`@Library()`, `script { }` etc.), but this approach is very explicit and powerful - you can use library in any place in your pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try out [Jenkins Templating Engine](https://boozallen.github.io/sdp-docs/overview/1/index.html).
It gives you comprehensive Jenkins pipeline governance and templating capability.